# EMGU crashes when trying to write out greyscale image to VideoWriter

Tags: .net, opencv, video-capture, emgucv

Can anyone tell me why EMGU throws an exception when trying to write out a greyscale image?  Here is what I do:

gCam.StartAcquisition();
            Debug.WriteLine("recording...");

```
        //Bitmap safeImage = new Bitmap(xiImageWidth, xiImageHeight, 
        //System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

        Bitmap safeImage = new Bitmap(xiImageWidth, xiImageHeight,
                                                               System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale );

        //Emgu.CV.Image<Gray, Byte> currentFrame;
        Emgu.CV.Image<Gray, UInt16> currentFrame;

        gCam.GetImage(safeImage, XI_CAPTURE_TIMEOUT);

        //currentFrame = new Image<Gray, Byte>(safeImage);
        currentFrame = new Image<Gray, UInt16>(safeImage);
        currentFrame.Save("testImage.bmp");

        startTime = DateTime.Now;

        if (emguVideoWriter.Ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
                emguVideoWriter.WriteFrame(currentFrame);
        }
```

When I use MONO8 and Image I have no problem, but if I try to go 16-bit I get this exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
exception caught while recording a frame! ex=System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel(Int32 x, Int32 y)
   at Emgu.CV.Image`2.set_Bitmap(Bitmap value) in C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-x64 2.4.0.1717\Emgu.CV\Image.cs:line 2866
   at Emgu.CV.Image`2..ctor(Bitmap bmp) in C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-x64 2.4.0.1717\Emgu.CV\Image.cs:line 213
```

This has been driving me crazy as I don't see why I cannot write out 16-bit images.  I was hoping VideoWriter would make my life easier but instead it is just complicating matters.  I almost feel like just writing out the raw bytes myself at this point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer.  Line 2669 of Image.cs (EMGU source code) says this:

```
    /*
    //PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale is not supported in .NET
    else if (typeof(TColor) == typeof(Gray) && typeof(TDepth) == typeof(UInt16))
    {
       return new Bitmap(
          size.width,
          size.height,
          step,
          PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale;
          scan0);
    }*/
```

Not supported!  I wish the exception said this!